# Category page should not display child categories

Tags: wordpress

I need that each category of Wordpress will display only its own posts and not those of its child categories. How is this done?

I need posts that are in sub-categories to appear only in their sub-categories and not to appear in the parent category (where I want to see only posts that were marked for that parent category.
However, in the parent category I get all posts that are marked to appear in the sub-category of that parent category.

For example, if I have category "cars" and underneath it, subcategories "Fiat", Ford", "Honda", I see the Fiat posts both in the subcategory "Fiat" and in the parent category "Cars".

How can we fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [`parse_tax_query` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_tax_query/) to exclude children of the current category

You can try something like this: (*Requires php 5.3 +*)

```
add_action( 'parse_tax_query', function ( $query ) {
    if ( 
        ! is_admin() 
        && $query->is_main_query()
        && $query->is_category()
    ) {
        $query->tax_query->queries[0]['include_children'] = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working!
Unfortunately I can't vote just yet as my "reputation score" is not high enough but as soon as it is, I'll vote for this answer.Thank you. This is working!

Answer (score 0):

Works only with **WordPress >= 3.3**.

In your functions.php theme file:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','hide_subcategories_function',20,1);

function hide_subcategories_function($the_query) {
    if(get_bloginfo('version') >= 3.3 && function_exists('is_main_query')) {

        if(!$the_query->is_admin && !$the_query->is_preview && $the_query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] == false && $the_query->is_category && $the_query->is_main_query()) {

            $cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $the_query->query_vars['category_name'], 'category');

            $the_query->set('category__in',array($cat->term_id));

        }

    }
    return $the_query ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, with this code in the functions.php file, I get a blank screen when I try to get into a category page.